# Structure App using Methods/threads

Tags: android

I know this is a fundamental java question, but i am relatively new to java.
How do i structure the code attached (monitoring) within a UI.
What the code does is just log values, and if certain conditions are activated, it does stuff. The loop () method does pretty much everything, but there are a few small things done by the preceding methods.
Let's say in the UI, I have a 'calibrate' button, which if pressed, runs a calibrate method/thread, and a 'monitoring' button which runs a different 'monitoring' method/thread. The problem is, these methods/threads are at the moment defined in their own project as classes. My ideas are along the lines that i need to construct these 2 classes and then call the methods i want from them in response to UI interaction. However, if i call just the method, for example:

```
 if (monitoring button) {
monitoring.method1;
}
```

this means that i can't do anything in parallel to that, so I need to make what happens in those classes into thread somehow.

Cheers,

Rokky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at AsyncTask, this will allow you to run logic in a background thread, leaving your activity free to respond to the user.